# scala, filter RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

i have val:

```
val key: RDD[String]= Seq("0000005","0000001","0000007").toRDD
```

and

```
val file2: Array[String] = Array(("0000005", 82, 79, 16, 21, 80),
("0000001", 46, 39, 8, 5, 21), 
("0000004", 58, 71, 20, 10, 6),
("0000009", 60, 89 33 18 6),
("0000003", 30, 50, 71, 36, 30),
("0000007", 50, 2, 33, 15, 62))
```

I would like to filter in file2 exists element in "key"

I want something like this:

```
0000005 82 79 16 21 80
0000001 46 39 8 5 21
0000007 50 2 33 15 62
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified this to standard `Scala` collection types:

```
val keys = Seq("0000005","0000001","0000007")

val all = Seq("0000005 82 79 16 21 80",
"0000001 46 39 8 5 21", 
"0000004 58 71 20 10 6",
"0000009 60 89 33 18 6",
"0000003 30 50 71 36 30",
"0000007 50 2 33 15 62")
```

Here is the filter function that will give your resuklt:

```
val filtered = all.map(_.split(" ").toList)
                  .filter{ case x::_ => keys.contains(x) }
                  .map(_.mkString(" "))

println(filtered) // -> List(0000005 82 79 16 21 80, 0000001 46 39 8 5 21, 0000007 50 2 33 15 62)
```

See [Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WToX185/0)

Comment: If the files are small enough, they can turned into an `Array` and this solution can be used. However, if the OP wants to use `RDD`s  `keys.contains(x)` won't work among other things.

Comment: This answer uses the Seq (List) contains method, which does a linear lookup. This solution won't scale well

Answer (score 0):

First, need to map `file2` for key->value structure: (I assume all the numbers in file2 are actually strings..):

```
val file2Map: RDD[(String, Array[String])] = file2.map(value => (value.head, value)).toRDD
```

Now, if you do:
    keys.join(file2Map).take(10).foreach(println)

The output would be something like:

```
(0000005, (0000005, 0000005 82 79 16 21 80)
(0000001, (0000001, 0000001 46 39 8 5 21)
(0000007, (0000001, 0000001 50 2 33 15 62)
```

And from that it's easy to get only the second tuple from the value.